# 3 colors loop in a grid

Tags: java, loops, grid

I cannot post any picture because I just created this account but this is the link to it:

https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2013/cmsc131-12/Fall2013Proj2/InformationAndPictures.htm

```
if (countryCode == 2){

if (height % 3 == 0 && width % 3 == 0 ){
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col = col + 1){
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row = row + 1){
            grid.setColor(row , col, Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col = col + 1){
        for (int row = height / 3; row < height; row = row + 1){
            grid.setColor(row, col, Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col = col + 1){
        for (int row = height / 2 + 1; row < height; row = row + 1){
            grid.setColor(row , col, Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
}
```

So far this is what I have but I just can't get the red and green color to balance correctly I know I something is wrong with my equation but I just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third loop seems wrong. It will only work if there are 6 rows. For more number of rows you would need a general formula. Try this -

```
for (int col = 0; col < width; col = col + 1){
    for (int row = height/3 * 2; row < height; row = row + 1){
        grid.setColor(row , col, Color.RED);
    }
}
```